# Template in export mysql to excel in php

Tags: php, mysql, excel, export

I export from MySQL to Excel with this code.
I have no problem when executing this code without CMS,
but when I use this code in my CMS the template is in export and I want to get this query result.

```
$db_name = "test";
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Could not connect to server!");
$table_name = 'users';
$select_db = mysql_select_db($db_name, $link); 
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
$query = "SELECT * from users";
$result = mysql_query($query, $link) or die("Could not complete database query"); 
$num = mysql_num_rows($result); 
$num2=mysql_num_fields($result);
$header="";
for ($i = 0; $i < $num2; $i++) { 
    $header .= mysql_field_name($result, $i) . "\t"; 
} 
if ($num != 0) {
    $_xml ="<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?>\r\n";
    $_xml.="<dataroot xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'>\r\n";
        while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            $_xml .="\t<qq>\r\n";

            if($row[0]<>'')    $_xml.="\t\t<q>".$row[0]."</q>\r\n";
            if($row[1]<>'')    $_xml.="\t\t<a>".$row[1]."</a>\r\n";
            $_xml.="\t</qq>\r";
        }
    $_xml.="</dataroot>";
    header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=filename.xls"); 
    header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
    header("Expires: 0"); 
    header("Lacation: excel.htm?id=yes");
    print($_xml); 
} else {
  echo "No Records found";
}`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if I understand your problem. But in the end you are talking about getting a query-result. ALSO you defined an attachment into the header. You cant get output on your website AND download a file at the same step.

If output is generated, the download will be corrupted. So you have to decide: Output or download. If you really need both another way would be: First generate your output, then redirect the user to a blank download-page which appends the attachment. If correctly done, you should visually stay on your main-page while the download-page loads up the attachment after the output on your main-page is done.

Correct me if I got something wrong here.

Ps: Instead of

> $var = "";

better use

> unset($var);.